# salt cmd.run if no result dont return ERROR: non-zero exit code

Tags: salt-stack

I am running a command on my salt master that checks if a process is running, if it is not running the output i get is:

```
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

I tried adding >/dev/null to the end of my salt command which stops the error but this means i get no output if my process is running which is no good as i need to do something with the output if it is running.

Is there a way i can stop this Error being returned but keep the output returning when there is any?

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the stderr to /dev/null

```
salt '*' test.ping 2>/dev/null
```